If $X$ is compact + Hausdorff, then $X$ has a partition of unity.
A partition of unity on a space $X$ is a collection $\Phi$ of continuous functions from $X$ to $R^{+}$ (the nonnegative reals) such that, at each $x \in X, \varphi(x) \neq 0$ for only finitely many $\varphi \in \Phi$, and $\sum_{\varphi \in \Phi} \varphi(x)=1$. $\Phi$ is called locally finite iff each $x \in X$ has a nhood on which all but finitely many $\varphi \in \Phi$ vanish. $\Phi$ is subordinated to a cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $X$ iff each $\varphi \in \Phi$ vanishes outside some $U \in \mathscr{U}$.
My goal: If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then $X$ has a partition of unity.
There is a nice proof of this result?

A compact Hausdorff space is normal, so the standard result applies.

@TedShifrin so, where I can find?

Any reasonable book on point-set topology?

What I found is books with exercises about, without proofs...

You haven’t searched very thoroughly. Look at pp. 225-6 of Munkres’s Topology, 2nd edition.

gosh, i forget Munkre's, thanks a lot!

@Kempa The following link contains what you want: General Topology.
